# style calculation for gpu accelerated animation in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

This is a chrome only question. I'm using chrome 56 on OSX, but I also tested this on Windows 8 using chrome 57.

I have an animation that is gpu accelerated, using `will-change: transform` and a keyframe animation using `transform: translateY(...)` to move an element around the screen.

```
.block {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vh;
    background-color: black;
    animation: move 5s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% { transform: translateY(0%); }
    50% { transform: translateY(400%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0%); }
}
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/nicokoenig/full/PmYaOZ/

The animation itself is handled on the chromes compositor thread and is therefor not affected if the main thread is blocked.

When I record a timeline, I still see that there is a style calculation for each frame.

Why does chrome need to recalculate styles, even if the animation is handled on the compositor thread?

---

UPDATE

I reviewed my code and added three types of animations.

- the first animtion is using a fixed viewport unit (vh) to translate the box.
- the second animation is using a fixed pixel value to translate the box.
- the third animation is using a percentage value to translate the box.

I also added button to block the main thread - if I hit the button:

the first and second animation will still move around the screen, the third one freezes.

**I think that is the answer - an animatoin using translate with percentage values needs to recalculate styles during the whole animation.**

Comment: see [screenshot of timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlivh.png)

Comment: Updated demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/nicokoenig/full/PmYaOZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is a known chrome bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711645
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389359